# How MPFR Library Calculation Accuracy Works

Tags: c, gmp, mpfr

I confess that I am having trouble understanding the `MPFR` library, I am trying to calculate the square root of a large number but I am not sure how to define the precision of the `mpft_t root` variable or what is the best way of rounding.

my code is as follows:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpfr.h>


int main(){

    mpfr_t bigNumber, bigNumber2, root2;

    unsigned long int size = 1000000;

    mpfr_init2(bigNumber, size);
    mpfr_init2(bigNumber2, size);
    mpfr_init2(root2, size);

    mpfr_ui_pow_ui(bigNumber, 8, 20000, MPFR_RNDZ);

    mpfr_sqrt(root2, bigNumber, MPFR_RNDA);

    mpfr_pow_ui(bigNumber2, root2, 2, MPFR_RNDA);

    return 0;
}
```

But regardless of the precision set for `mpz_t root`, the result is often not satisfactory.

The result of  `mpfr_pow_ui (bigNumber2, root, 2, MPFR_RNDA)`  is most often different than `mpfr_t bigNumber`, and I don't mean the floating value, but the entire part.

How to find out the precision needed to perform a certain calculation?

what is the best form of rounding for this calculation?

why does this inaccuracy happen?

Comment: We'll need an [mre], please.

Comment: right, I corrected the question.

Comment: It has been a while since I worked with MPFR, so I am not sure exactly what your code is requesting of it in precision, but I suspect you are using the same precision for `bigNumber2` and `root2`. In this case, consider that, for some precision such that the ULP is approximately one part in P relative to the number, if we have some y with square root x, the calculated square root may be around x+1/(2p), due to the required rounding, and then the square of that is x^2+2x/(2p) + 1/(4p^2), which is approximately y + x/p. So it is not unexpected that calculating `sqrt(y)^2` will differ from `y`.

Comment: In other words, a small relative error in the square root leads to a large relative error in the square of that square root. You would have to calculate the square root with much more precision than the square in order to recover the original number most of the time, and, even then, I suspect there may be some cases that fail. Why are you trying to get the square of a square root to equal the original number anyway? Floating-point arithmetic is generally intended to be an approximation; you should not expect results identical to real-number mathematics.

Comment: This is for study only. In that case, I was just studying the accuracy of the library. Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: MPFR just rounds each operation correctly, regarding each input as exact. It does not track the accuracy in a sequence of operations. You have other tools for that.

Comment: In the case of a slightly modified version of the code in the post, the result is apparently exact. (The modification is to print the difference.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works fine (on GCC 9.3.0 and MPFR 4.1.0) and gives back the original number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpfr.h>


int main()
{
    mpfr_t bigNumber, bigNumber2, root2;
    unsigned long int size = 100000;
    mpfr_init2(bigNumber, size);
    mpfr_init2(bigNumber2, size);
    mpfr_init2(root2, size);
    mpfr_ui_pow_ui(bigNumber, 8, 20000, MPFR_RNDD);
    mpfr_out_str (stdout, 10, 0, bigNumber, MPFR_RNDD);
    putchar ('\n');
    putchar ('\n');
    putchar ('\n');
    mpfr_sqrt(root2, bigNumber, MPFR_RNDD);
    mpfr_out_str (stdout, 10, 0, root2, MPFR_RNDD);
    putchar ('\n');
    putchar ('\n');
    putchar ('\n');
    mpfr_pow_ui(bigNumber2, root2, 2, MPFR_RNDD);
    mpfr_out_str (stdout, 10, 0, bigNumber2, MPFR_RNDD);
    putchar ('\n');
    putchar ('\n');
    putchar ('\n');
    putchar ('\n');
    return 0;
}
```